# Why isn't Docker more transparent about what it's downloading?

Tags: docker

When I download a Docker image, it downloads dependencies, but only displays their hashes.  Why does it not display what it is downloading?

For example:

```
➜  ~ docker run ubuntu:16.04
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:16.04' locally
16.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
b3e1c725a85f: Downloading 40.63 MB/50.22 MB
4daad8bdde31: Download complete
63fe8c0068a8: Download complete
4a70713c436f: Download complete
bd842a2105a8: Download complete
```

What's the point in only telling me that it's downloading `b3e1c725a85f`, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

An image is created on layers of filesystems represented by hashes. After it's creation, the base image tag may point to a completely different set of hashes without affecting any images built off of it. And these layers are based on things like run commands, the tag to call it something like ubuntu:16.04 is only added after the image is made.

So the best that could be done is to say 4a70713c436f is based on adding some directory based on a hash of an input folder itself, or a multi-line run command, neither of which makes for a decent UI. The result may have no tagged name, or it could have multiple tagged names. So the simplest solution is to output what's universal and unchanging for all scenarios, an unchanging hash.

To rephrase that pictorially:

```
b3e1c725a85f: could be ubuntu:16.04, ubuntu:16, ubuntu:latest, some.other.registry:5000/ubuntu-mirror:16.04
4daad8bdde31: could be completely untagged, just a run command
63fe8c0068a8: could be completely untagged, just a copy file
4a70713c436f: could point to a tagged base image where that tag has since changed
bd842a2105a8: could be created with a docker commit command (eek)
```